# Installing GRUB on an USB stick: Keep having this "cannot find EFI directory" error

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, uefi

I'm trying to install grub on a USB stick in order to make it bootable.
I want to make it bootable to make a USB multiboot, to carry more than one distro in one single USB (ie. rescatux and tails). 
I've done this:

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/MULTIBOOT/boot
```

and then:

```
sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --boot-directory=/media/MULTIBOOT/boot /dev/sdc1
```

And I get this error:

> Installing for x86_64-efi platform. grub-install: error: cannot find
>   EFI directory.

I've got Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and it's 64-bit.

This is my USB configuration:
[image]

This is the very first time that I'm trying this and I'm a bit lost here, should I use `/dev/sdc1` or `/dev/sdc`?

I've tried (with the similar result), this other alternative:

```
sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --boot-directory=/media/victoria/MULTIBOOT/boot /dev/sdc
```

Where is the problem?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please tell us in more general terms, what you want to achieve! Is it 'an installed system' (installed like into an internal drive, but in a USB drive)? Or is it a live or persistent live system? What kind of multiboot system is it (several live systems or several installed systems or a mixture)? Are you starting from a particular system created with a particular tool, or are you making the system 'from scratch'? Is it only Ubuntu and Ubuntu flavours, or also other linux distros and maybe Windows or MacOS?

Comment: You show it mounted at /media/victoria/MULTIBOOT. But are trying to install to /media/MULTIBOOT?? And you do not use a device unless you also created that as a mount point which can then be confusing.

Comment: @sudodus I want to make it bootable to make a USB multiboot, to carry more than one distro in one single USB (ie. rescatux and tails).

Comment: OK, so several linux live systems. You know that there are tools for it? For example http://multibootusb.org/ and https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/ - I think it is easiest to use one of these tools, but if you want to learn about 'grub and iso' you can start from this link and links from it, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

Comment: I didn't know about those tools. Thanks!! I'll try them first then!

Comment: The last I checked, YUMI did not work for creating EFI-bootable media, which is what you seem to be trying to do. Of course, if booting in BIOS mode is acceptable, YUMI might work OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't provide a complete answer to your question because some aspects of GRUB configuration and installation are beyond my skill level and because of some ambiguity about what you want to do (as specified by sudodus in his comment to your question). That said, I can make several observations and suggestions that may be helpful:

- When you install GRUB to a normal running EFI system from Ubuntu, GRUB will become `EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` on the [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) with an NVRAM entry pointing to that location.
- EFI-bootable USB drives, by contrast, typically boot from a boot loader called `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` on the USB drive's ESP. This filename is typically called the *fallback filename,* and EFIs are supposed to look for that filename as a last resort if no NVRAM entry points to a valid boot loader, or if the user selects the boot medium from a built-in boot manager menu. Thus, to install to this location you must either adjust the `grub-install` command (and I'm not even 100% positive that it supports this) or copy the files manually.
- Complicating the preceding, if the computer uses Secure Boot, Ubuntu installs a program called *Shim* (`shimx64.efi`), and creates an NVRAM entry pointing to it, rather than to `grubx64.efi`. Likewise, to boot an external medium, the original `shimx64.efi` must be named `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`. In either case, Shim then launches `grubx64.efi` in the same directory as Shim.
- When *not* using Secure Boot, Ubuntu's GRUB looks for a `grub.cfg` file in the `/boot/grub` directory, which is not likely to be the ESP. When booting with Secure Boot active, though, `grubx64.efi` looks for `grub.cfg` in the same directory as `grubx64.efi`. That `grub.cfg`, though, looks for and loads `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, so the effect is the same, but the path is more complex. In either case, there's a dependence on both the ESP and whatever partition holds `/boot/grub`. Some distributions set things up differently; Fedora, for instance puts the final `grub.cfg` and all related files on the ESP.
- The `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file is built (or re-built) by configuration scripts that run whenever you install a new kernel or GRUB binary. This works fine for a single-boot system, but if you're multi-booting with another Linux distribution, things get messy fast. In particular, if Distribution A's GRUB controls the boot process and you update the kernel for Distribution B, GRUB won't show the new Distribution B kernel until you run `update-grub` (or something similar) in Distribution A.

Between these factors, to do what you want with GRUB, chances are you must install to the fallback filename rather than to the standard filename; you might or might not need to squeeze Shim into the picture; and you may need to tweak your `grub.cfg` for your two-distribution setup. That's a lot to do. If I needed to do all this with GRUB, my approach would be to install both distributions to the USB drive as if it were an internal hard disk and then move/rename GRUB (or Shim) to the fallback filename. This will have the advantage that you shouldn't need to monkey with the `grub.cfg` file. One big caveat is that if you wanted to use something that installs in an unusual way (like via UNetbootin or Rufus rather than Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer), that might change the equation in a way that will require some completely different approach. It looks like you're trying to use Ubuntu on your hard disk to install GRUB to the USB drive to be used in booting from the USB drive. This approach might work if you're far more of a GRUB expert than I am, but there are enough obscure variables at play that your approach is likely to be a mine field of complications.

Another method is to use my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) You'd need to install it to the fallback filename, but rEFInd scans for kernels at boot time, so it's less likely to be disrupted by installing a new kernel in one distribution when you used the other distribution to install GRUB or rEFInd. OTOH, if you want to use Secure Boot, you'll need to jump through extra hoops (documented on [rEFInd's Secure Boot page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html)) to get it working, likely on every computer that you use to boot the USB drive. You might also need to create `/boot/refind_linux.conf` files for *both* your distributions to handle distribution-specific kernel options. (See the [rEFInd Linux documentation,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/linux.html) and especially the bottom half or so of that page, for information on this.)